# Pig multiply a number from a table to all the values of another table

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two tables:

```
A: (feature:chararray, value:float)

B:(multiplier:charray, value:float)
```

where A is a table with thousands of rows and B has only one row.

What I wanna do is take all the rows in A and multiply A.value by B.value.

e.g.

```
A:[('f1', 1.5) , ('f2', 2.3)]

B:[('mul', 2)]
```

I'd like to product a table C

```
C: [('f1', 3), ('f2', 4.6)]
```

Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `CROSS` and a `FOREACH ... GENERATE`.

```
X = A CROSS B;
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE A::feature, A::value * B::value;
```

The above code has not been tested.

Answer (score 2):

If You are very sure that the 2nd table has only one row then take the first column

of 2nd table and hardcode the same value as last column in 1st table and then

do the inner join and the you can easily multiply

Let say first file as plain.txt

```
(f1,1.5)
(f2,2)
```

here is the second file as multi.txt

```
(mul,2)

A = load '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/plain.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(feature:chararray,value:double);

B = load '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/multi.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(operation:chararray,no:int); 

C = foreach A generate feature,value,'mul' as ope;  

D = join C by ope, B by operation; 

E = foreach D generate feature,(value*no) as multiplied_value;
```